# decimals=0 nor working between all steps

Tags: formatting, decimal, nouislider

I have this setup:

```
                <script>
                    // Behaviour
                    jQuery("#lp-slider").noUiSlider({
                        start: [ 30000 ],
                        connect: "lower",
                        range: {
                            'min': [ 2000,100 ],
                            '20%': [ 20000,1000 ],
                            '40%': [ 30000,2000 ],
                            '60%': [ 50000,2000 ],
                            '80%': [ 70000,3000 ],
                            'max': [ 100000 ]
                        },
                        // Number formatting
                        format: wNumb({
                            decimals: 0
                        })
                    });

                    // Link value to input
                    jQuery("#lp-slider").Link('lower').to(jQuery('#kwh'));
                </script>
```

I bound it to an input field. It's working good when the first value is 10.000. But when the first value is below 10.000 I get weird decimals after the comma like "13099.99997" even with decimals=0.

How can I make sure that really only 100s are outputted when I set the way like above in the code?

Thanks in advance for any help!
getimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `format` option on the slider affects the `.val()` readout. You can use the same formatter on the `.Link()`, like so:

```
jQuery("#lp-slider").Link('lower').to(jQuery('#kwh'), null, wNumb({
    decimals: 0
}));
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leongersen/qsw10hac/).

**Edit in response to comment:**

You've got yourself a tricky bug there! On line 77, you have:

```
<script src="/landing/0custom/nouislider/jquery.nouislider.all.min.js"></script><script src="/landing/0custom/nouislider/wNumb.js"></script>
```

`jquery.nouislider.all.min.js` already contains `wNumb`. The `wNumb.js` you've included is an older version [before this bugfix](https://github.com/leongersen/wnumb/commit/617d608be7753d0ba288dd88820d278d5b6e1a6a). Remove `wNumb.js` to resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I copied your snippet and unfortunately I still have the same behaviour. What could be the reason?

You can see it live here: https://goo.gl/r8HAQr

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue. All I had to do is download the newest version of [wNumb](http://refreshless.com/wnumb/) and put it into my project folder where the old one was stored. Then everything worked perfectly! Hope this helps!